# Не получается установить файлы для графики из учебника Страуструпа

Tags: c++

Читаю учебник Бьярне Страуструпа "Программирование, принципы и практика с использованием C++". Дошел до 12 главы, не получается установить заголовочные файлы для графики из учебника. Поставил FLTK, вроде работает. Скачал все нужные заголовочные файлы с сайта автора. Попытался собрать из них библиотеку получил это(не все, там куча всего было):

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: SW, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Graph.cpp
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(7): error C2653: Shape: не является именем класса или пространства имен
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(8): error C2270: draw_lines: модификаторы недопустимы для функций, не являющихся членами
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(9): error C3861: color: идентификатор не найден
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(9): error C2228: выражение слева от ".visibility" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(9): note: тип: unknown-type
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(9): error C2065: points: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(9): error C2228: выражение слева от ".size" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(9): note: тип: unknown-type
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(10): error C2065: points: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(10): error C2228: выражение слева от ".size" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(10): note: тип: unknown-type
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(11): error C2065: points: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(11): error C2228: выражение слева от ".x" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(11): error C2228: выражение слева от ".y" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(11): error C3861: fl_line: идентификатор не найден
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(14): error C2653: Shape: не является именем класса или пространства имен
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(15): error C2270: draw: модификаторы недопустимы для функций, не являющихся членами
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(16): error C2065: Fl_Color: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(16): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед идентификатором "oldc"
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(16): error C2065: oldc: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(16): error C3861: fl_color: идентификатор не найден
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(18): error C2065: lcolor: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(18): error C2228: выражение слева от ".as_int" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(18): note: тип: unknown-type
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(18): error C3861: fl_color: идентификатор не найден
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(19): error C2065: ls: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(19): error C2228: выражение слева от ".style" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(19): note: тип: unknown-type
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(19): error C2228: выражение слева от ".width" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(19): note: тип: unknown-type
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(19): error C3861: fl_line_style: идентификатор не найден
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(21): error C2065: oldc: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(21): error C3861: fl_color: идентификатор не найден
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(22): error C3861: fl_line_style: идентификатор не найден
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(28): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "<"
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(28): error C7525: Для встроенных переменных требуется по меньшей мере уровень "/std:c++17"
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(28): error C4430: отсутствует спецификатор типа - предполагается int. Примечание. C++ не поддерживает int по умолчанию
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(29): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(29): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(53): error C2065: Point: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(53): error C2146: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ")" перед идентификатором "p1"
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(53): error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "{"
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(53): error C2447: {: отсутствует заголовок функции (возможно, используется формальный список старого типа)
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\graph.cpp(62): error C2653: Polygon: 
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\simple_window.cpp(14): error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "initializer list" в "int"
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\simple_window.cpp(14): note: 
1>c:\users\nail1\source\repos\sw\sw\window.cpp(70): error C3861: run: идентификатор не найден
1>Создание кода...
1>Сборка проекта "SW.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Попытался добавить исходники напрямую в проект, получил это:

```
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: 1, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
1>Graph.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\fl\x.h(37): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory,
1>GUI.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\fl\x.h(37): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory,
1>main.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\fl\x.h(37): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory,
1>Simple_window.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\fl\x.h(37): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory,
1>Window.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.13.26128\include\fl\x.h(37): fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл включение: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory,
1>Создание кода...
1>Сборка проекта "1.vcxproj" завершена с ошибкой.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========
```

Comment: рискну предположить, что проект автора под линукс, а собираете вы его, судя по всему, в винде. Это может вызывать кучу конфликтов

Comment: Написано что под винду.